# using strlen to find length of user input c

Tags: c, arrays, string, input, strlen

I am trying to create an array that to store a user's input, and I need the array to be the exact length of the user's input. I would like to take the length of the user's input, and use this as the length of the array. How can I do this with strlen? Is there any better way?

Comment: `malloc` a small size and `realloc` more memory as required.

Comment: *Why* do you need the array to be the exact length of the input?

Comment: Why strlen ? What are you trying to achieve ? What should that array contain ? Numbers ? Letters ? Edit your question and be more specific

Comment: More importantly, do you allow binary input or just general text? 1) Allocate a reasonable size; 2) read input and store it; 3) Needs more space than the allocated? 4) Yes, then reallocate; 5) No, done. - Ultimately you can count how many bytes you've read and reallocate the buffer (downsize it) to fit that amount.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to acquire memory as you need it. I would use `CHUNKSIZE` more than `4` but I restricted it for easy testing.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CHUNKSIZE   4

int main(void){
    char *text;
    int maxlen = CHUNKSIZE;
    int index = 0;
    int ch;

    text = malloc(CHUNKSIZE);
    if(text == NULL)
        exit(1);
    printf("Enter your text:\n");

    while((ch = getchar()) != EOF && ch != '\n') {
        text[index++] = ch;
        if (index >= maxlen) {
            maxlen += CHUNKSIZE;
            text = realloc(text, maxlen);   
            if(text == NULL)
                exit(1);
        }
    }
    text[index] = 0;                // terminate

    printf("%d You entered: %s\n", maxlen, text);
    free(text);    
    return 0;
}
```

Program session:

```
Enter your text:
A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
You entered: A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Comment: Nitpicking: `maxlen` and `index` should be of `size_t` or `unsigned` at least.

Comment: @alk agreed, and also in proper programs the result of `realloc` should be tested before losing the original value.

Comment: Also using a do-while loop would make the 1st call to `malloc()` unnecessary. You got my 1+ however ... ;-)

Comment: @alk thank you, but providing `*text = NULL` as initialisation.

Comment: @alk I did it that way, because after the loop a `'\0'` is written even when there is no input.

Comment: Oh yes, I missed this case, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Before writing your own function, you can try the following code:

```
char *str;
scanf("%ms", &str); // <--- Note the & before str

// Do something with str...

free(str);
```

This is an extension to ISO C standard [supported on all POSIX.1-2008-conforming systems](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/scanf.html).