# read file line by line including multiple newline characters

Tags: c, string, file

I am trying to read a file of unknown size line by line including single or multiple newline characters.
for example if my sample.txt file looks like this

```
abc   cd er  dj
text

more   text


zxc cnvx
```

I want my strings to look something like this

```
string1 = "abc   cd er  dj\n";
string2 = "text\n\n";
string3 = "more   text\n\n\n";
string4 = "zxc convex";
```

I can't seem to come up with  solution that works properly. I have tried following code to get the length of each line including newline characters but it gives me incorrect length

```
while((temp = fgetc(input)) != EOF) {
    if (temp != '\n') {
        length++;
    }
    else {
        if (temp == '\n') {
            while ((temp = fgetc(input)) == '\n') {
                length++;
            }
        }
        length = 0;
    } 
}
```

I was thinking, if I can get length of each line including newline character(s) and then I can malloc string of that length and then read that size of string using fread but I am not sure if that would work because I will have to move the file pointer to get the next string.

I also don't want to use buffer because I don't know the length of each line. Any sort of help will be appreciated.

Comment: To get the length of each line only. If I don't do that then it will keep adding length.

Comment: Allocate memory for a string. Read the file with `fgets`. If there is no `newline` present at the end of the string (and you are not at the end of the file), the whole line was not read, so you reallocate for a longer string and carry on reading onto the end of the previous data.

Comment: lines don't have an average size. Some lines may be too big and some may be too small. I also don't know how big file is going to be. It can either consist few lines or 16,000 lines book.

Comment: @WeatherVane how memory should I allocate for string? I don't know the size of each line. Should I just allocate big chunk of memory and then reallocate according to the need?

Comment: Allocate any amount. When it is too small, reallocate with double the size, or with a fixed increment. You can even do that several times per line, if required.

Comment: There is an answer to a similar question but using getchar [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652985/using-strlen-to-find-length-of-user-input-c/36653195#36653195) which shows the use of `realloc`. For the example text shown, the memory was reallocated several times as the text was entered.

Comment: I will try to implement something like that. Thanks for the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lines are just short and there aren't many of them, you could use `realloc` to reallocate memory as needed. Or you can use smaller (or larger) chunks and reallocate. It's a little more wasteful but hopefully it should average out in the end.

If you want to use just one allocation, then find the start of the next non-empty line and save the file position (use `ftell`). Then get the difference between the current position and the previous start position and you know how much memory to allocate. For the reading yes you have to seek back and forth but if it's not to big all data will be in the buffer to it's just modifying some pointers. After reading then seek to the saved position and make it the next start position.

Then you could of course the possibility to [memory-map the file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file). This will put the file contents into your memory map like it was all allocated. For a 64-bit system the address space is big enough so you should be able to map multi-gigabyte files. Then you don't need to seek or allocate memory, all you do is manipulate pointers instead of seeking. Reading is just a simply memory copying (but then since the file is "in" memory already you don't really need it, just save the pointers instead).

---

For a *very* simple example on [`fseek`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fseek) and [`ftell`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/ftell), that is somewhat related to your problem, I put together this little program for you. It doesn't really do anything special but it shows how to use the functions in a way that could be used for a prototype of the second method I discussed above.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file = fopen("some_text_file.txt", "r");

    // The position after a successful open call is always zero
    long start_of_line = 0;

    int ch;

    // Read characters until we reach the end of the file or there is an error
    while ((ch = fgetc(file)) != EOF)
    {
        // Hit the *first* newline (which differs from your problem)
        if (ch == '\n')
        {
            // Found the first newline, get the current position
            // Note that the current position is the position *after* the newly read newline
            long current_position = ftell(file);

            // Allocate enough memory for the whole line, including newline
            size_t bytes_in_line = current_position - start_of_line;
            char *current_line = malloc(bytes_in_line + 1);  // +1 for the string terminator

            // Now seek back to the start of the line
            fseek(file, start_of_line, SEEK_SET);  // SEEK_SET means the offset is from the beginning of the file

            // And read the line into the buffer we just allocated
            fread(current_line, 1, bytes_in_line, file);

            // Terminate the string
            current_line[bytes_in_line] = '\0';

            // At this point, if everything went well, the file position is
            // back at current_position, because the fread call advanced the position
            // This position is the start of the next line, so we use it
            start_of_line = current_position;

            // Then do something with the line...
            printf("Read a line: %s", current_line);

            // Finally free the memory we allocated
            free(current_line);
        }

        // Continue loop reading character, to read the next line
    }

    // Did we hit end of the file, or an error?
    if (feof(file))
    {
        // End of the file it is

        // Now here's the tricky bit. Because files doesn't have to terminated
        // with a newline, at this point we could actually have some data we
        // haven't read. That means we have to do the whole thing above with
        // the allocation, seeking and reading *again*

        // This is a good reason to extract that code into its own function so
        // you don't have to repeat it

        // I will not repeat the code my self. Creating a function containing it
        // and calling it is left as an exercise
    }

    fclose(file);

    return 0;
}
```

Please note that for brevity's sake the program doesn't contain any error handling. It should also be noted that I haven't actually *tried* the program, not even tried to compile it. It's all written  ad hoc for this answer.

Comment: @samadbond It depends. Do you need to keep *all* lines in memory at once? What are you supposed to do with the data you read? Oh and I've edited the answer to include a third way which doesn't need any seeking or even (active) memory allocation by you.

Comment: I will add those strings to my linked list. I am trying to convert plain text into html text and the reason I am trying to read newlines is because html has paragraph tags

Comment: memory-mapping seems bit complex for me. I think there is an easy solution to read each line including newlines.

Comment: I have also never used fseek before so I don't know how to make fseek pointer to pointer to the start of next string

Comment: @samadbond Added a simple example on how to use `fseek` and `ftell` is a way that might be useful for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for detailed explanation. I will try implement this code

Comment: `Read a line: abc   cd er  dj`  
`Read a line: text`  
`Read a line: `  
`ext`  
`Read a line: more   text`  
`Read a line: `  
`ore   text`  
`Read a line:`  
`ore   text`  
`Read a line: zxc cnvxext`

Comment: Your program changes my text a bit. previous character is getting added to next lines.

Comment: @samadbond As noted I hadn't tested the code. Turns out I forgot to terminate the string. Fixed now (together with a couple of other things).

Comment: There is one small problem with your above solution. It leaking some memory. Val grind shows 5 allocs and 4 free. I can't figure out the extra malloc.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg (fixed a typo for you, a `to` -> `do`)

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thanks

Comment: @samadbond Probably because I forgot to call `fclose` at the end of the program.

Answer (score 0):

You get the wrong length. The reason is that before you enter the loop:

```
while ((temp = fgetc(input)) == '\n')
```

you forgot to increment `length` as it has just read a `\n` character. So those lines must become:

```
else {
    length++;                // add the \n just read
    if (temp == '\n') {      // this is a redundant check
        while ((temp = fgetc(input)) == '\n') {
            length++;
        }
        ungetc(temp, input);
    }
```

---

EDIT

After having read the first non `\n`, you now have read the first character of the next line, so you must unget it:

```
ungetc(temp, input);
```

Comment: it only fixes the length of first string. Length for others strings is still incorrect.

Comment: Hope my last edit fixed it. Unfortunately I can't test it at this moment.

Comment: Then please click on the up-arrrow to approve my answer. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are trying to write your own implementation, you can use [the standard POSIX `getline()` function](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getdelim.html):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main(void)
{
    FILE *fp;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    fp = fopen("/etc/motd", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(1);
    while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) {
        printf("Retrieved line of length %zu :\n", read);
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    if (ferror(fp)) {
        /* handle error */
    }
    free(line);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but your solution doesn't solve my problem. I am trying to read newlines as well.

Comment: @samadbond *Thanks for replying but your solution doesn't solve my problem. I am trying to read newlines as well.*  What makes you think `getline()` doesn't read newlines?  Did you *read* the documentation for `getline()`?  It says "Upon successful completion, the getline() and getdelim() functions shall return the number of bytes written into the buffer, **including the delimiter character if one was encountered before EOF**."

Comment: It only includes single new line character. When I ran your code with my sample.txt file, it prints length of 'text' 5, instead of 6

Comment: @samadbond So if a line consists only of a single `\n` newline character, add it to the previous line.  Something like `if (!strcmp(line,"\n")){ strcat(previous_line, line); } else { previous_line = line; previous_len = len }` It'll be a bit more complex than that, but even with keeping track of the previous line, that's a whole lot easier than reimplementing and debugging `getline()`.  Reimplementing and debugging library functions is *hard*.  See the [glibc `getdelim()` internals](https://fossies.org/dox/glibc-2.24/iogetdelim_8c_source.html)